# my wifi is not working need help on 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm having problems connecting to my WiFi here is the troubleshooting steps i did after researching it on the Internet but it was not helping as i can see the WiFi being listed but I'm not able to connect it to the Internet after removing the hard block. can anybody help me with this.

```
shan@shan:~$ sudo rfkill list all 0: phy0: Wireless LAN     Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN  Soft blocked:
no  Hard blocked: no

shan@shan:~$ sudo lshw -class network   *-network               
        description: Wireless interface
        product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
        vendor: Broadcom Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
        logical name: wlan0
        version: 01
        serial: c4:46:19:62:1a:b8
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) latency=0 multicast=yes
 wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
        resources: irq:17 memory:fbd00000-fbd03fff   *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
        logical name: eth0
        version: 02
        serial: f0:4d:a2:be:7a:8d
        size: 100Mbit/s
        capacity: 100Mbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd
 autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.5 latency=0 link=yes
 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
        resources: irq:45 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d0c10000-d0c10fff memory:d0c00000-d0c0ffff
 memory:fb300000-fb31ffff
```

Comment: Have you tried to install the proprietary driver for it? Please search "Driver" in your dash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and wifi should work.